# Criar um array para ChartJS com dados do Firestore + Angular 9

Tags: array, angular, firestore

Para popular um gráfico de dados mensal/anual preciso que o Array seja agrupado por data.

Dados vindos do Firestore:

```
this.chartsSrv.chartGeral().subscribe((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    let item = doc.data();
    this.dataArray.push({
      "id": item.id,
      "dataPost": moment(item.dataPost.toDate()).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
    });
  })
})

console.log(this.dataArray);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O gráfico exige 3 informações de acordo com os formatos a seguir.

**Pico:** Ele alterna conforme o valor máximo da propriedade length do array que precisaria criar.

**Meses:** [Jan, Fev, Mar ... ] conforme os valores que vem de cada grupo do array no item dataPost

**Total por Mês:** aí entra na questão que preciso agrupar por data e pegar a propriedade length de cada grupo.

Para ilustrar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ok, o que você já tentou?

Comment: @veroneseComS tentei essa resposta mas sem sucesso  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/342198/l%c3%b3gica-para-agrupar-dados-em-array-javascript?rq=1